# Apache SSLProxyEngine on

Tags: apache-2.2, g-suite

Folks,
  Trying to proxy my domain to a Google Apps built website.

As you know, Google websites carry the following URL pattern:

```
https://sites.google.com/site/sitename/
```

How do I get http://meme.com to look as https://sites.google.com/site/sitename/

Is it possible, and what is the correct way to setup a domain name for this site?  If if I have meme.com, why is this setup not working?:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLProxyEngine on
   RewriteEngine on
   ProxyPass / https://sites.google.com/site/sitename/
   ProxyPassReverse / https://sites.google.com/site/sitename/
</VirtualHost>
```

Logs:

```
[Mon Sep 10 19:22:19.829225 2012] [ssl:info] [pid 3629:tid 140571093870336] [remote 74.125.228.7:443] AH02005: SSL Proxy: Peer certificate CN mismatch: Certificate CN: *.google.com Requested hostname: sites.google.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off the [`SSLProxyCheckPeerCN`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycheckpeercn), then try again to see what happens.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53006

Comment: This helped... but not all objects are loading... plus this in logs:[Tue Sep 11 00:13:25.778915 2012] [proxy_html:warn] [pid 25435:tid 140451545843456] [client 72.21.198.68:21458] AH01422: No i18n support found.  Install mod_xml2enc if required
[Tue Sep 11 00:13:30.793259 2012] [ssl:info] [pid 25435:tid 140451545843456] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 72.21.198.68:21458] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aslo specify a certificate, keyname and CA certificate if needed like:

```
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
```

Comment: I should have added that ...  Obviously the certs are in.

Comment: Its possible that the *.google.com vs sites.google.com wildcard certificate is the reason why this is failing....